# html input=server

Tags: php, html, input

I have a website written in html/php on my server. I also have a script which loads a file and returns some graphs. I can load a file from my pc using `<input type="file" (...)/>`.

The problem is: I'd like to load files not from my hard drive but directly from the server - I mean files are already uploaded, now I want people to be able to select files they want and analyse them with my script. Let's say they are at this location: `/home/user/www/source/`. How can I do it? Is there some smart function to replace `<input>`?

Answer (score 2):

If all the files in a certain folder are valid then you can [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) them and create links or a select list. If you want to manipulate the contents of a file, you'll need to [open](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) it with PHP, [read](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) the contents, and output the data into html.

Answer (score 0):

The images are stored on a harddrive, how about just using the img-tag?

Answer (score 0):

After uploading the files, your script could append that file to a list of uploaded files... something like

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
data1.txt
```

Then you can use your script to dynamically list the files...

```
<?
$f = file ('uploads.txt');

print '<ul>';
for ($i=0; $i<count($f); $i++) {
    print '<li><a href="analyze.php?f='.$f[$i].'">'.$f[$i].'</a></li>';
}

print '</ul>';

?>
```

Of course, you'd have to put your graph creation code in analyze.php so that it returns the graph corresponding to the selected file.